# How does moisture exist in atmosphere?

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science, phase-transition

Moisture is the water vapor in air surrounding us where the temperature is 25 degrees Celsius (say). But the water exists as vapor only above 100 deg C at a pressure of 1 atm.

Then how does moisture exist at room temperature, because at this temperature water should be in liquid state and not as vapor?

Comment: Do a google search for Raoult's Law.  Read the information carefully and think about withdrawing your question or asking something much more specific.

Comment: Your assumption about water vapor existing only above 100 C is incorrect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the premise is incorrect.

Comment: I don't think a Physics-question based on a misunderstanding of Physics is off-topic on [Physics.SE].

Comment: Super cooled vapor.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapour_pressure_of_water

Answer (score 3):

Boiling point is defined as the temperature when the vapor pressure is equal to the atmospheric pressure vapor pressure is dependent on temperature and at a specific temperature dynamic equilibrium will be reach between the number of molecules who have enough kinetic energy to escape as a gas from the liquid and the gas molecules who lose energy and condense back into the Liquid. If you want to read more do read up on Vapor pressure and Raoult's law (more in the fields of chemistry and intermolecular forces than physics and thermodynamics)

Also please be more specific with the question, this is all I can help based on what you told me

Answer (score 1):

Vapor is the gaseous form of water below boiling point and steam is the gaseous form above or at boiling point. Vapor should be condensed below dew point temperature to form water.